# SceneKit – Display multiple scenes in same SCNView

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scene

Is there a way I can display multiple scenes in the same SCNView at the same time? So let's say I have a ball in `ball.dae` and a pyramid in `pyramid.dae`. So these are separate scenes and I would like to show both at the same time.

Currently I only have one and I create it like this:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "world1.dae")!
```

If I just create another one below then it just displays the second one... :/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I already figured it out. The thing is to not add another scene but nodes from the 2nd scene to the first like this:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "world1.dae")!
let subScene = SCNScene(named: "pyramid.dae")!

let pyramid = subScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("pyramid", recursively: true)!

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pyramid)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made two SCNNode extension functions that clone nodes
from another scene:

```
extension SCNNode
{

    func addNodeClonesWithNames(#fromScene: SCNScene,   nodeNames: [String]  )
    {
        for nodename in nodeNames
        {
            self.addClonedChildNode( fromScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName(nodename, recursively: true)! )
        }
    }

    func addClonedChildNode(node: SCNNode)
    {
        self.addChildNode(node.clone() as! SCNNode)
    }
 }
```

in your view controller, loading two scenes here:

```
let scnMain   = SCNScene(named: "world1.dae")!
let scnAssets = SCNScene(named: "props.dae")!


// then add some nodes from the assets scene to the main scene's
// root node by name:

scnMain.rootNode.addNodeClonesWithNames(fromScene: scnAssets, 
           nodeNames: ["btnStartEngine","btnStop","btnReverse","btnEject"])
//
```

Of course, this works not only on a root node, but on all SCNNodes.
I use cloning here so that the original stays intact for multiple usage.

I hope this is useful. So glad this is Swift.. Regards. Ted

Comment: Well thanks, but I had the problem figured out a while ago already ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Xcode 6.2 with iOS 8.2, I had to slightly change the code

```
  func getNodeFromScene(colladaFile: String)  -> SCNNode {
    var subScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/\(colladaFile).dae")
    let geometryNode = subScene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName(colladaFile, recursively: true)!
    return geometryNode!
  }
```

subScene to subScene?